# Generate a 64bit unique ID

Tags: java, android, random

Is there a good way to generate a good and unique 64bit ID on Android? I have read on this topic but nothing so far seems to be fitting.

I thought about using `ANDROID_ID`, but there are reasons that I wont do that, as this seems to be dependant on the manufacturers keeping standarts (which some wont).

`UUID.randromUUID()` will generate a to big ID (as I want 64bit).

The ID does not have to be kept after the App was deleted also it does not need to in any kind secure (e.g. secure against manipulation).

Comment: Unique across what?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html#nextBytes(byte[]), assuming that by "unique" you mean "unlikely to have a collision".

Comment: Cant you take UUID and take first(any) 64bits?

Comment: What about `long i = 0; ++i;` ? Unique, looks good...

Comment: CommonsWare is right, I am fine with "unlikely to have a collision"

Comment: For 64 bits, use DES and encrypt 1, 2, 3, ... with the same key for unique IDs.

Comment: And how will this generate an unique ID on the apps? I mean, if all apps encode 1 with (how should they know which numbers are used already?) then the IDs will be the same everywhere...